# Elastic beanstalk cluster behavior on update or node failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to know if there is the possibility to do the following things with elastic beanstalk.

1. Automatically add an instance, up to the maximum defined instance count, when a node fails. I have health checks that report a node is unhealthy and elastic beanstalk removes it from the ELB but doesn't add another instance to satisfy the minimum instance count. I would expect it to do that automatically or is there a configuration for that?
2. Automaticall add an instance, up to the maximum defined instance count, when doing a rolling update. A node will not be healthy for some time when doing a rolling update so the minimum healthy instance count is not satisfied. I would expect elastic beanstalk to always respect the minimum healthy instance count. Is there a way to do that other than changing the minimum count before doing an update?

Answer (score 0):

For (1) Elastic Beanstalk configures your AutoScaling to use EC2 health checks by default. You can configure your autoscaling group to use ELB health checks if you would like. The documentation for this configuration is available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentconfig-autoscaling-healthchecktype.html

You essentially use an ebextension that modifies the health check type for the AutoScaling resource in your environment.

Although note the warning in the documentation:

> Enabling this option can cause your environment to continually terminate and replace instances if the Elastic Load Balancing health check fails soon after an instance starts. If this happens, change the health check type back to EC2 in the Auto Scaling management console, or reverse the configuration change and redeploy your environment.

You may need to play with your ELB health check to ensure it is stable enough to prevent cycling instances at a high rate.

For (2) the only option available currently is to manually update the minimum instance count if you want to maintain the same instance count during an update. Otherwise at least one instance can be down during a rolling update.